# REST ASSURED TEST creating my own given() method

Tags: java, spring, testing, java-8, rest-assured

I have more than two similar REST ASSURED rests e.g.

```
 @Test
 public void makeSureThatGoogleIsUp() {
     given().auth().oauth2(getToken()).contentType("application/json")
     .when()
     .get("http://www.google.com")
     .then()
     .statusCode(200);
 }

 @Test
 public void makeSureThatGoogleIsUp() {
     given().auth().oauth2(getToken()).contentType("application/json")
     .when()
     .get("https://stackoverflow.com")
     .then()
     .statusCode(200);
 }
```

And I would've like to create method called `given()` to make method less complex and readable.

```
private [something] given(){
    return given().auth().oauth2(getToken()).contentType("application/json")
}
```

making my methods use my given instead of rest assured one:

```
 @Test
 public void makeSureThatGoogleIsUp() {
     given()
     .when()
     .get("http://www.google.com")
     .then()
     .statusCode(200);
 }

 @Test
 public void makeSureThatGoogleIsUp() {
     given()
     .when()
     .get("https://stackoverflow.com")
     .then()
     .statusCode(200);
 }
```

something like here: but I dont really know what kind of return type this method could have or if its even possible.
Sorry, question can be trival, but seriously I'm stuck here.
Any helps? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns a `RequestSpecification` object: http://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured/2.4.1/com/jayway/restassured/specification/RequestSpecification.html

Also a side note if you're creating your own `given()` -- it might be better to name the method something else as someone else using it might assume it's the jayway version and confuse themselves when they get errors.

Comment: You're totally right with naming convension and with return type.
Your answer solved my problem, Thanks and have a nice day :)

Comment: Glad to know that it helps. Do select this as the right answer so that the thread can be closed. Have a great day yourself! :-)